# Rails DateTime to Time dst check

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, time, dst

```
Time.now
2017-03-14 12:07:59 -0600
Time.now.dst?
true

tt = Time.parse(DateTime.strptime("03/14/2017 12:07AM", "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M%p").to_datetime.to_s)
2017-03-14 00:07:00 +0000
tt.class
Time
tt.dst?
false
```

This also fails

```
DateTime.strptime(value, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M%p").to_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").to_datetime.change(offset: '-0500').to_time.dst?
```

Why does the DateTime conversion to Time fail dst?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's due to the fact that the converted time is missing the time zone (example -0600). Try the following,

```
 tt = Time.parse(DateTime.strptime("03/14/2017 12:07AM -06:00", "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M%p %z").to_datetime.to_s)
```